# Overbrace formatting in an integral

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to replicate some guidelines in the calculus book for my students to use as a reference, but the formatting is getting messed up. As you can see, there are several formatting issues. First off, how can I get the "2k+1" to be the regular exponent size? Secondly, those giant gaps in the second integral need to go! I haven't really played with over/underbraces much, so I really don't know what I'm doing! Thanks for your help! =)

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \int\!\sin^{\overbrace{2k+1}^{\text{odd}}}x\cos^n x \,dx
    = \int\!\overbrace{(\sin^2x)^k}^{\text{convert to cosines}}\cos^n x\overbrace{\sin x\,dx}^{\text{save for $du$}}
    = \int\!(1-\cos^2x)^k\cos^n x\sin x\,dx
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Thanks to all that replied, but now I have a second issue. When the exponent is even, the overbrace seems to be too small. I have tried fiddling with mathclap, but it doesn't solve the issue. =(  Not sure if this needs to be posted as a new question, but I'll try just posting it here first. The code for the new issue is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \int\!\sec{\overbrace{^{2k}}^{\text{even}}}x\tan^n x\,dx
    = \int\!\overbrace{(\sec^2x)^{k-1}}^{%
            \substack{\text{convert to} \\ \text{tangents}}}
                \tan^n x\overbrace{\sec^2 x\,dx}^{\text{save for $du$}}
    = \int\!(1+\tan^2 x)^{k-1}\tan^nx\sec^2x\,dx
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \int\!\sin{\overbrace{^{2k+1}}^{\text{odd}}}x\cos^n x \,dx
    = \int\!\overbrace{(\sin^2x)^k}^{%
        \substack{\text{convert to}\\\text{cosines}}}
            \cos^n x\overbrace{\sin x\,dx}^{\text{save for $du$}}
    = \int\!(1-\cos^2x)^k\cos^n x\sin x\,dx
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

The problem of exponent in the first integral I solve with put all exponent in `\overbrace`, for second comment I suggest to wrote it in two lines by help of `\substack` and on this way it make shorter.

[image]

**Edit:**
As I mentioned in comment, `overbrace` is not possible make shorter from its minimal length. In such cases the solution can be to use `bracket` from `mathools` package instead `braces`. With it and help of `mathclap` (also from `mathtools`) you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\int \sec\overbracket[0.5pt]{^{2k}}^{\mathclap{\text{even}}}x\tan^n x\,dx
    & = \int \overbrace{(\sec^2x)^{k-1}}^{%
            \substack{\text{convert to} \\ \text{tangents}}}
                \tan^n x\overbrace{\sec^2 x\,dx}^{\text{save for $du$}} \\
    & = \int (1+\tan^2 x)^{k-1}\tan^nx\sec^2x\,dx
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited a follow up question, if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it.

Comment: @Jon, this is problem of braces. If distance between both ends of brace is shorter then necessary length to draw arches of braces, the it is extent to its minimum length. With other words, you need to redefine brace. Other way is that you use ``bracket`` instead of brace. For this see manual for ``mathtools``. Since here is very late, I need go to sleep, so the example how to use brackets, I will prove in the morning, if this will be still actual.

Answer (score 7):

I would use a combination of things to make the output look a little better:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \int \sin^{\overbrace{\scriptstyle 2k+1}^{\scriptstyle\text{odd}}}x\cos^n x \,\mathrm{d}x
    = \int \overbrace{(\sin^2x)^k}^{\mathclap{\text{convert to cosines}}}\cos^n x\overbrace{\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x\vphantom{{}^k}s}^{\mathclap{\text{save for $\mathrm{d}u$}}}
    = \int (1-\cos^2x)^k\cos^n x\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

1. A forced `\scriptstyle` inserts a superscript/exponent-size font.
2. [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides `\mathclap` which removes any horizontal spacing inserted by math content (thereby letting the `\overbrace` content spill over the `\overbrace` edge). Also, a vertical strut the height of a `k`-exponent makes the latter two `\overbrace`s line up better.

---

For very narrow `\overbrace`s, results are sub-optimal. Perhaps you can just point to it using an arrow:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \int \sec^{\overset{\underset{\downarrow}{\mathclap{\scriptstyle\text{even}}}}{2k}}x\tan^n x \,\mathrm{d}x
    = \int \overbrace{(\sec^2x)^{k-1}}^{\mathclap{\text{convert to tangents}}}\tan^n x\overbrace{\sec^2 x\,\mathrm{d}x}^{\mathclap{\text{save for $\mathrm{d}u$}}}
    = \int (1+\tan^2x)^{k-1}\tan^n x\sec^2 x\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it looks to me like "odd" has gone down a size..  another `\scriptstyle` just before `\text{odd}` would fix that.  i tried patching the definition of `\overbrace` to keep the argument in the appropriate size, but that affected the positioning of the "limit", which shifted off to the side (as would be appropriate for `\limits` in anything smaller than `\textstyle`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for that, I missed it.